# Lwjgl rotation not work

Tags: java, 3d, rotation, lwjgl

I have an object that can rotate on all axes, my problem is that if you rotate the object on the y axis (eg 90 °) the rotation on the z axis is incorrect because it rotates over the x axis,Instead, rotation on the x axis continues to function perfectly, If the y axis is set to 0 °, the rotation of the z axis returns to function correctly.

to rotate and translate object i use this code:

```
public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f translation , float rx, float ry, float rz , float scale){
    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
    matrix.setIdentity();
    Matrix4f.translate(translation,matrix,matrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rx),new Vector3f(1, 0, 0) , matrix,matrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(ry),new Vector3f(0, 1, 0) , matrix,matrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rz),new Vector3f(0, 0, 1) , matrix,matrix);
    Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale, scale, scale), matrix, matrix);
    return matrix;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an intrinsic singularity in Euler angle rotations, called *Gimbal lock*. Use *quaternions* for rotations instead (can specify an arbitrary axis).

Comment: I tried to generate the matrix with quaternions, but the result was usually very likely i miss the implementation

Comment: @MaurizioTerreni what do you mean by "miss" the implementation?

Comment: https://github.com/maurizioterreni/OpenGL/blob/master/src/com/unifi/ing/engine/utils/Maths.java I try to implement the quaternion (look row 34) but the problem is the same. maybe is not correct my implementation

Comment: @MaurizioTerreni ok so what's wrong with it? what are you "missing"? you seem to have the right quaternion to matrix conversion code

Comment: @spug Actually, your answer lacks of accuracy. Using quaternions help but isn't enough to solve the OP's concern, you can still have some gimbal lock if you misuse them but they are helpful to implement a linear solution to fix it. There is a non linear solution too, this is what is used in JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation (I'm its maintainer). You mustn't use Eulerian transforms with quaternions. This article explains very well the mathematical reason behind gimbal lock: https://sundaram.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/mathematical-reason-behind-gimbal-lock-in-euler-angles/